# Splitting Linklist in two parts

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

Given a list, split it into two sublists — one for the front half, and one for the back half. If the number of elements is odd, the extra element should go in the front list. So `FrontBackSplit()` on the list `{2, 3, 5, 7, 11}` should yield the two lists `{2, 3, 5}` and `{7, 11}`.

code is this.

```
void FrontBackSplit(Node *head, Node **front, Node **back) {
  if (!head) return;  // Handle empty list
  Node *front_last_node;
  Node *slow = head;
  Node *fast = head;
  while (fast) {
    front_last_node = slow;
    slow = slow->next;
    fast = (fast->next) ? fast->next->next : NULL;
  }
  front_last_node->next = NULL;  // ends the front sublist
  *front = head;
  *back = slow;
}
```

Problem is I am not getting best run-time and sometimes expected output.

Comment: Do you have list length ready? If yes, divide by 2, advance by that many nodes and split.

Comment: What's the problem ? What happens when you call the function ?

Comment: How do you determine "not the best runtime" and what's wrong with the output?

Comment: `(!head)` means list is empty? checking condition.

Comment: @HenkHolterman... If the number of elements are even then it is not dividing them equally in two parts.

Comment: @Krishna for odd it divides?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan...Yes

Comment: Isn't your final back should be front_last_node?

Comment: I don't see any problem with efficiency in this code.

Comment: @all... May I know why it is downvoted???

Comment: @Krishna I am not down-vote but, You should write you question in such a way that people don't have to ask in comment (you question is not clear) look at [this question and revision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781485/significance-of-in-pointers-c-language) history how it was written and how I update

Comment: actually since last few days I am active on SO, and I check that people doing edits for just points. I think question is very clear...

Comment: @Krishna *`I am not getting best run-time and sometimes expected output.`* ? what does it mean ? are you still lokking for an answer ?

Comment: @Krishna when you comment someone use `@` before the name...

Answer (score 1):

Generally, your code works well for even-sized lists. Consider a list of 4 elements A -> B -> C -> D -> NULL and take a look at your algorithm trace.

```
A    slow, fast, head
B
C
D
NULL

A    front_last_node, head
B    slow
C    fast
D
NULL

A    head
B    front_last_node
C    slow
D
NULL fast
```

Then you erase the link B->C and return two lists: A -> B and C -> D. This is exactly the wanted behavior of this function, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way ;

Use a loop to calculate how many elements are in the linked list.

If its couple - the first list is between head(the address of the first element) to i=n/2 element. The second list is between i=0.5n+1 element to the last one.

Else the first list is between the head to the i=0.5n+1 element and the second is between i=0.5n+2 to the last one.

To make it easy, when you run the loop to calculate the number of elements, use a variable to keep the place of the last one and the middle one, so it will be easy to use them when needed.